# Proving the complex funtion is analytic when the sequences are converging uniformly.

Tags: complex-analysis

I am working on the following problem:

Suppose $D$ is the unit disk centered at the origin in $\mathbb{C}$ and for each natural number $n,\,\,f_n:D\to\mathbb{C}$ is an analytic function. Prove that if the sequence $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $D$ then $f$ is analytic.

It would be a great help if anyone can give me any idea how to tackle this problem. Thank you very very much.

Comment: Is $D$ the open or the closed disk?

Comment: @FrankLu, nothing mentioned about $D$, how would it be changed based on whether $D$ is open or closed?

Comment: Have you learned about Morera's theorem?

Comment: @GyuEunLee, Yes. To be honest was thinking that I have to use it, but didn't not have the courage to write this idea here. going through the theorem I still couldn't see how to use it? Thanks a lot again. Thank you very much.

Comment: You can try to prove the limit function $f$ is holomorphic by showing it integrates to $0$ along all closed contours (in fact triangles suffice). To do this, you'll need to recall how uniform convergence interacts with Riemann integration.

Comment: "Prove that" needs to be changed to "Prove that if"

Comment: @zhw. Thank you very much.